# Insert new rows if a duplicate doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dozen new rows that I need to insert into a table that are not coming from another table. I also need to check whether there are duplicates based on a couple columns that aren't using any constraint.

Currently my solution is to first insert those rows into a temp table and then use INSERT INTO [...] SELECT with a WHERE clause that uses NOT EXISTS.

It seems like there has to be a better way to do this and I'm looking for suggestions.

(Using SQL Server 2012)

Just as a bit of context, the use case for this is a database migration process where rows need inserting, the migrations may be run multiple times and cannot insert duplicate data, and also cannot throw a unique constraint violation as that would end execution of the migrations.

Comment: You could try a merge clause but personally I use and like the solution you are currently using.  I just don't use a temp table.

Comment: Like Vulcronos said, I would just use the method you are using, but get rid of the temp table seems like an extra step in your process.

Comment: Here is another vote for your current method.  It allows you more flexibility in seeing what rows get in and don't get into the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the TSQL Merge .  IT can handle looking up your duplicates and only inserting if it is a new record. (WHEN NOT MATCHED) clause

See [Merge Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: I'd still have to use another table (whether it be temporary or otherwise) to use merge, correct?

Comment: @Moismyname Yes, however if you are dealing with a small set of rows, then a Table Variable might be the most effective.

Comment: Ah! For some reason I never think of table variables. Good call there.

Answer (score 1):

When using SQL Server's [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), duplicates will silently fail.